# Remove stdout output from tf.Session due to init in a loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, session, verbosity

I've come to stack overflow because no one else seems to have asked this question before. When running my tensorflow model I use it inside a loop to do regression analysis. I use tf.Session inside the lop

loop:
    with tf.Session as sess:
          ...code rest of code

When I run the neural network it spits out all the tensorflow/core information in the loop and makes my actual output (for me to visualize) useless. I'd like to either re-direct the output or find a way to make it less verbose or completely silent.

I've gone through most of the documentation from tensorflow and the Session documentation doesn't reveal anything to me. Here is the current output to the terminal.

> 2019-07-22 16:09:46.813546: I >tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu >devices: 0
>   2019-07-22 16:09:46.815548: I >tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect >StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
>   2019-07-22 16:09:46.817433: I >?>tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
>   2019-07-22 16:09:46.818613: I >tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
>   2019-07-22 16:09:46.819902: I >tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow >device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8698 MB memory) -> >physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, >compute capability: 7.5)